# What is the exact term for resolving all sub-domains (*.stackexchange.com) to www.stackexchange.com

Tags: terminology

The related question is asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456474/whats-the-english-words-for-pan-domain-name), and I cannot figure out it.

Answer (score 5):

It is called a [DNS wildcard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_DNS_record)

*As an aside (it's off-topic here): The standards are defined in [RFC 4592](http://www.rfc-archive.org/getrfc.php?rfc=4592). See also https://serverfault.com/questions/215042/dns-wildcard-vs-cname-subdomains*

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean redirecting all subdomains to the main domain? A **domain bin** ?

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for the term "URL canonization".

Comment: I think you mean URL canonicalization or URL normalization. Canonizing a URL is up to the Space Pope.